# List Items show javascript functions on only 1st item (Items have same ID)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making an `ul` and each `li` has the same ID to keep the code simple, clean, and efficient.

When I apply my scripting functions they only apply to the first `li`.

How do I apply the functions to the `li` that is hovered?

Thank you

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/killamilla/GfqDj/10/)

Comment: Why are you doing it in pure javascript ?

Comment: How does it make code simple, clean and efficient? If you want more than one element to match, it sounds like you need `class`, not `id`.

Comment: @karthikr I suppose I could use all css for it!

@MichaelKrelin-hacker I am doing this to keep all my elements the same and wasn't aware they needed to be labeled as `class` not `id`

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect to have more than one Element with the same id. Since document.getElementById relies the fact that there is only one element with an id, it will not do what you expect. You should change the code to use class instead of id.

---

Alternatively you could use querySelector instead which makes no assumptions regarding the id:

```
function openHiddenItems(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id !== 'list-item') return;
  evt.target.querySelector('#red-square').style.visibility = 'visible';
  evt.target.querySelector('#yellow-circle').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function closeHiddenItems(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id !== 'list-item') return;
  evt.target.querySelector('#red-square').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  evt.target.querySelector('#yellow-circle').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Also make sure you pass the event to your open and close functions. I would recomend separating JS code and HTML:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#list-item');

for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', openHiddenItems);
  elements[i].addEventListener('mouseout', closeHiddenItems);
}
```

EDIT: There is a back-forth between the functions if you hover over the place the elements become visible/hidden. It can be solved as well, by seeing if the currently hovered element is inside the `#list-item`.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GfqDj/11/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to get this working but couldn't unfortunately. I got what I've been trying to do going with CSS, but would really like to see this work as well.

Could you send me a fiddle? I am new to scripting.